# Chrome Share API

Tags: html, google-chrome

Does anyone know if the new share button in Chromium-based browsers has an API? I currently have the following HTML embedded on my website which activates the system share sheet of your device, but I'd rather have it use the Chrome one when possible.

```
    <style>
        a {
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: black;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            scroll-behavior: none;
        }

        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .zoomA {
            width: 60px;
            height: auto;
            /* ease | ease-in | ease-out | linear */
            transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
        }

        img {
            border: 0;
        }

        .zoomA:hover {
            transform: scale(1.4);
        }

        body {
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, San Francisco, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        svg {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        button,
        .button {
            display: inline-flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: auto;
            padding-top: 8px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            color: #b7b7b7;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: 1.1;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #00cc69;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #000;
        }

        button:hover,
        .button:hover {
            border-color: #00cc69;
            background: #000;
            color: #b7b7b7;
            outline-color: #000;
            text-decoration-color:#000;
        }

        button:active,
        .button:active {
            border-color: #00cc69;
            background: #000;
            color: #b7b7b7;
            outline-color: initial #000;
            text-decoration-color:#000;
            background-image: none;
        }

        .share-button,
        .copy-link {
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }

        .share-button,
        .share-dialog {
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <button class="share-button" type="button" title="Share">
        <svg>

            <use href="#share-icon"></use>

        </svg>
        <span>Share</span>
    </button>
    <svg class="hidden">
        <defs>
            <symbol id="share-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
                stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-share">
                <path d="M4 12v8a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-8"></path>
                <polyline points="16 6 12 2 8 6"></polyline>
                <line x1="12" y1="2" x2="12" y2="15"></line>
            </symbol>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <script id="rendered-js">
        const shareButton = document.querySelector('.share-button');
        const shareDialog = document.querySelector('.share-dialog');
        const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');
        shareButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
            if (navigator.share) {
                navigator.share({

                    title: 'example.com',

                    text: 'Check out this website I found.',

                    url: 'https://example.com'
                }).

                    then(() => {

                        console.log('Thanks for sharing!');

                    }).

                    catch(console.error);

            } else {
                shareDialog.classList.add('is-open');
            }
        });
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
            shareDialog.classList.remove('is-open');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. The Google Developers [recommend](https://web.dev/web-share/) to use the Web Share API like you do when you want to have an UI. 
But why would you even want to implement it the other way? It is much more compatible to use an API that does at least work on a few browsers more than only in Chrome, even if the Web Share API still does not provide [full Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Share_API#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Feel free to check it on my website, RyderCragie.com. You can see what happens when you click the share button, but it doesn’t always work in some Chromium-based browsers, like Avast Secure Browser on macOS.

Comment: Yeah, that's the browser compatibility I talked about. I'm sure they will add some more browsers in the future but so long as they don't I guess you have to either do it without the Web Share API or accept the low browser support.